# Toad output data grid only shows 500 Rows at a time

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using Oracle 11g with Toad 12.5.1.1 and the output grid only shows me 500 rows at a time. 
Is there a way to make toad display all the results at a time or is there a way to find the number of rows returned even though the grid only shows 500 records ?

Comment: What's the use of seeing more then 500 rows? If you want to export: Toad fetches all anyway, if you want to count: Why not just count (i.e. by select count(*)), if you want to see something special: select what you want to see.

Comment: This is late to the party, but probably this question would be a better fit for "SuperUser":  https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 8):

Well, that is considered a feature.

If you enter the grid and hit <kbd>Ctrl+End</kbd> it will fetch all rows for you.

Comment: I dint know that and i think it will help. But Its still an added step. I am sure there would be some setting that would do this directly.

Comment: I am pretty sure there isn't since I would have set it a million times already.

Comment: Ctrl+End does indeed work -- Toad 16.2 in March, 2023

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you want to do, you need to set the `OCI Array Buffer Size` not the `Limit Grid Fecth`.

See here for more details:
http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/8909.aspx

Comment: That option was removed in recent releases (12.5 won't have it) although it's been reintroduced in the current 12.7 beta.

Comment: Mark, In toad options>Oracle>General i dont see OCI buffer size option. There is a DBMS o/p> default buffer size but i think that disabled for me.

Comment: If the option was removed in 12.5, but will return in 12.7, I don't think you have much of an option, other than to wait for 12.7 to be released, or move to 12.7 beta.....if the option isn't in the release you're using, you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the grid and use the option "Record count...". It will display on a floating windows the total record count.

Other option is to encapsulate your query in a `SELECT count(*) FROM (your query)`.